# cordova run ios: undefined is not a function

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, mobile, phonegap-cli

I have a cordova project and try to running iOS I executed:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova build ios
cordova run ios
```

Everything is fine with first 2 commands but with last command I got an error:
[image]

I'm using OS X El Capitan:
[image]

so any ideas?

Comment: be sure to add platform first "cordova platform add ios"

Comment: It's already there

Answer (score 0):

It seems your cordova installation was corrupted. Please reinstall the latest version of NPM and install cordova again using `sudo npm install -g cordova`.